# How to superpose text on image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually my balise section is under my image, or I want to superpose them ?

```css
#demo {
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 350px;
    text-align:center;
}
h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}
section {
    border:1px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top:-370px;
}
.credit {
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.500milligrammes.com/facticemagazine/final/news/obsession/img/1.jpg" alt="">
<section id="demo">
    <article>     
        <h2>Untamed Opulence</h2>
        <div class="credit">
            <hr style=" width:30px; margin:30px auto 15px auto">
            <p>Exclusive&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;July 15, 2015
                <br/>Serafima by Edwin S Freyer</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

How can I do ?
Here is my jsfiddle: [www.jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/ys484rpw/](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/ys484rpw/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Your link (if there was one) is not working.

Comment: Please turn your JSFiddle link into an actual hyperlink. Getting an error about needing to post code in your question before you can submit it? Well...then you should probably post your code.

Comment: I can't put an hyperlink, i've this error: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: @fatyfatoumata Precisely, which is why when you turn your JSFiddle link into a hyperlink, you're going to also want to include all relevant code in the question itself, not just off-site in a demo environment.

Comment: i tried all possibilities in help, i can't put a hyorkink, sorry

Comment: thank you for the edit  @Serlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given your image a class and set the image and demo section to position absolute with bottom 0

```js
$('article').readmore({speed: 500});
```

```css
#demo { margin: 0; max-width: 350px; text-align:center;}
h2 { margin: 0px; padding:0px;}
section { border:1px solid #eee; padding:20px!important;}
.credit { margin-top:0px; }

.abs, #demo {position:absolute; bottom:0;  max-width:350px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.500milligrammes.com/facticemagazine/final/addon/news/readmore.js"></script>
<img class="abs" src="http://www.500milligrammes.com/facticemagazine/final/news/obsession/img/1.jpg" alt="">
<section id="demo">
<article>

<h2>Untamed Opulence</h2>
<div class="credit">
<hr style=" width:30px; margin:30px auto 0px auto">
<p>Exclusive&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;July 15, 2015<br/>
Serafima by Edwin S Freyer</p>
</div>

</article>
</section>
```

Comment: it actually looks better if you set a max-height on the section but it moves the x down a bit http://jsfiddle.net/ys484rpw/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should watch " z-index " and I think if you round all of the elements in a single div and add 'position: absolute'. Sorry for my english i'm a beginner.